# Determine if the following sets are compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Determine if the following sets are compact. If not, give an example of a sequence contained in the set that does not posess a subsequence converging to a limit in the set.

(a) $\mathbb{N}$

(b) $\left\{1 + \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^2} \;\bigg\vert \;
 n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

(c) $\left\{1, \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5},\dots\right\}$

I know for a set to be compact it has to be bounded and closed. However, I am having some trouble understanding why these are or aren't compact. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll likely have seen a different definition of compactness as well, one with regards to sequences instead, which is equivalent here because we are working in a metric space. Alternatively, which of your sets are closed/bounded?

Comment: im not sure thats what i am having trouble determining..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)
$\mathbb N$ is not bounded and therefore not compact.

b)
An important property of compact sets is that they containing all their limit points.

the sequence $\sum \frac {1}{n^2}$ converges to an irrational number ($\frac {\pi^2}{6}$ but that isn't necessary to know.) and there are no irrational numbers in that set.  So the set does nto contain a limit point. and is not compact.

c) A set is compact if every open cover has a finite sub-cover.  And whatever open set covers the point $1$ there will exist an $N>0$ such that that cover will also cover every $a_n = \frac{n-1}{n}$ when $n > N.$  Leaving only finitely many points left to cover.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ contains all its limit points (any convergent real sequence converges to a real limit) but is certainly not compact. Instead, "containing all its limit points." is an equivalent definition for "closedness", so the argument still works.

Comment: i understand your reasoning for (c)...are you saying that info implies it is compact?

Comment: That's generally the definition of compact, that every open cover contains a finite subcover.

Comment: @B.Mehta  it is not a definition it is a property of compact sets.  Poor choice of wording on my part.  Thanks.